# erro ao usar waitActivityIndicator, como resolver?

Tags: aplicação-web, api, xamarin-forms

Estou fazendo uma conexão via web api no meu aplicativo, portanto não está aceitando o uso do "waitActivityIndicator", indica que ele não existe no contexto atual, abaixo o meu código, alguém poderia me dizer como resolver isso:

```
using EbsHelpDesk.Models;
using EbsHelpDesk.Services;
using EbsHelpDesk.Views;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Net.Http;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace EbsHelpDesk.Views
{
    public partial class LoginPage : TabbedPage
    {

        public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

        }

        protected async void BtnLogin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailEntry.Text))
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Erro", "Digite um nome de usuário válido", "Aceitar");
                emailEntry.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(senhaEntry.Text))
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Erro", "Digite uma senha", "Aceitar");
                emailEntry.Focus();
                return;
            }
            this.logar();


            App.Current.MainPage = new MainPageRoot();
        }

        private async void logar()
        {
            waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
            var loginRequest = new LoginRequest
            {
                Usuario = emailEntry.Text,
                Senha = senhaEntry.Text,
            };
            var JsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginRequest);
            var httpContent = new StringContent(JsonRequest);
            var resp = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://ativoproject.ebasesistemas.com.br");
                var url = "/login";
                var result = await client.PostAsync(url, httpContent);

                if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Erro", "Usuario ou senha incorretos", "Aceitar");
                    waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
                    return;
                }

                resp = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Erro", ex.Message, "Aceitar");
                waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
                return;

            }

            var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserName>(resp);
            waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
            await DisplayAlert("Bem vindo","vc esta logado", "Aceitar");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Somente um uso do `waitActivityIndicator` e a declaração dele no XAML seriam necessários para avaliarmos. Mas cade o AtivityIndicator no XAML?

Comment: Sim, eu entendi que eu tinha que declará-lo no meu xaml.... Eu inserir e deu tudo certo, obrigado!

Comment: coloque como resposta seu comentário para eu aprovar!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É necessário declarar o `ActivityIndicator` no seu XAML, informando o nome conforme vocÊ quer usar.

No seu caso seria algo assim:

```
<ActivityIndicator x:Name="waitActivityIndicator "
                   IsRuning="False"
                   IsVisible="False"/>
```

Nesse caso, quando o XAML for compilado ele criará uma variável do tipo `ActivityIndicator` com esse nome que estárá vinculada ao componente de tela.